# Error: The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.CRPE' threw an exception

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

After installing my Setup application (WinForms, Devexpress, vs2010)

I get 2 error messages after clicking the button to show the report:

The first:

> The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.CRPE' threw an exception.

And the second:

```
object reference not set to an instance of an object

    Consultez la fin de ce message pour plus de détails sur l'appel du débogage
juste-à-temps (JIT) à la place de cette boîte de dialogue.

************** Texte de l'exception **************
System.NullReferenceException: La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet.
   à CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.get_IsLoaded()
   à CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.NonHTTPCachedReportSource.GetReport(RequestContext context, Boolean bAddToCacheWhenCreated)
   à CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.LocalReportSourceBase.GetAvailableExportFormats(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
   à CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.ViewerDocument.GetAvailableExportFormats()
   à CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.PageView.CreateReportDocument(String rptURI)
   à CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.PageView.CreateNewReportDocument(String pageName)
   à CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer.CreateReportSource(Object reportSource)
   à CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer.set_ReportSource(Object value)
   à PixInfoGPC.Report.InitializeComponent()
   à PixInfoGPC.Report..ctor()
   à WindowsApplication1.Form1.simpleButton7_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   à System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   à DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   à DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseButton.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   à System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   à System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   à DevExpress.Utils.Controls.ControlBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   à System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   à System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   à System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

It's the last exception that I have after trying all solutions (adding all Crystal Reports dlls, Assembly merge, compiling to the x86 Platform).

Is there any information to get from this error message?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: That works in my compilation machine, But in another machine, its throw the exception, does not mean other problem ? @SonerGönül